# How can I plot a one-bar stacked bar chart in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

If I do a

```
bar([1 2 3 4 5;2 3 4 5 1], 'stacked')
```

I get two bars of stacked values corresponding to the two rows of my data - as I expected:
[image: example of two-bar stacked bar chart]

I would like to be able to similarly plot a stacked bar chart with only one bar, but if I try like this

```
bar([1 2 3 4 5], 'stacked')
```

I simply get five individual bars instead - no stacking:
[image]

So how can I produce a one-bar stacked bar chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This solution requires MATLAB 2019b)

Quoting the documentation:

> bar(y) creates a bar graph with one bar for each element in y. If y is an m-by-n matrix, then bar creates m groups of n bars.
>
> bar(x,y) draws the bars at the locations specified by x.

Using the first syntax, each element of a vector will become it's own bar. Using the second syntax, x defines how to understand a vector. In your case, you want a single stacked group:

```
bar(1,[1 2 3 4 5], 'stacked')
```

For comparison, with `Y=rand(1,5)`:
[image: example]

Comment: This works in R2019b; not in R2017b. So it seems to be a recent addition

Comment: What happendes in 2017b? Always the plot on the right?

Comment: The syntax `bar(1,[1 2 3 4 5], 'stacked')` is just not accepted. It gives an error `X must be same length as Y`

Comment: I tested on R2019a today and `bar(1, [1 2 3 4 5], 'stacked')` is not accepted either. So it's an R2019b addition

Answer (score 4):

Hacky solution:

```
bar([1 2 3 4 5;0 0 0 0 0], 'stacked')
set(gca,'xlim',[0.25 1.75])
```

Answer (score 4):

[Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60176170/2586922) answer is the way to go, but it only works in recent Matlab versions, starting at R2019b.

[Ander's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60175316/2586922) hacky solution works by creating a second, invisible bar. This has side effects; for example `axis auto` will extend the axes.

The following is an even hackier approach that avoids those issues. It creates the two bars and then removes the second by altering the graphical objects' data:

```
values = [1 2 3 4 5]; 
h = bar([values(:).'; NaN(1, numel(values))], 'stacked');
XData = vertcat(h.XData);
XData = num2cell(XData(:,1));
[h.XData] = XData{:};
YData = vertcat(h.YData);
YData = num2cell(YData(:,1));
[h.YData] = YData{:};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no direct solution! This may help:

```
bar([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13; nan(1,13)], 'Stacked');
set(gca,'xtick',1,'xlim',[0.25 1.75]);
```

[https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/295950-how-can-i-get-a-stacked-bar-graph-with-a-single-bar]